# Three js globe with boxes are non-responsive on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js

I have a three js globe with a box on each country to show the population: [www.nomdao.com](http://www.nomdao.com)

Whenever I open the website on mobile I can click on the boxes although it feels a bit lethargic meaning that sometimes I can't click on the boxes:

```
addEventListener('touchstart', (event) => {
event.clientX = event.touches[0].clientX
event.clientY = event.touches[0].clientY

  const doesIntersect = raycaster.intersectObject(sphere)

  if (doesIntersect.length > 0) mouse.down = true

  if (mouse.down) {

    const offset = canvasContainer.getBoundingClientRect().top

    mouse.x = (event.clientX / innerWidth)
      * 2 - 1
    mouse.y = -((event.clientY - offset)/ innerHeight)
      * 2 + 1

    gsap.set(popUpEl, {
      x: event.clientX,
      y: event.clientY
    })

    // event.preventDefault()
    // const deltaX = event.clientX - mouse.xPrev
    // const deltaY = event.clientY - mouse.yPrev

    // group.rotation.offset.x += deltaY * 0.005
    // group.rotation.offset.y += deltaX * 0.005

    // gsap.to(group.rotation, {
    //   y: group.rotation.offset.y, 
    //   x: group.rotation.offset.x,
    //   duration: 2
    // })
    // mouse.xPrev = event.clientX
    // mouse.yPrev = event.clientY
  }
}, 
{ passive: false}
)

addEventListener('touchend', (event) => {
mouse.down = false
})
```

Comment: I have tried your site on an iPhone and find that if I zoom in a little bit the boxes respond to touch. Incidentally Swaziland has been renamed eSwatini.

Comment: How can I increase the target area of my Raycaster?